# How to display data from mysql 8 in django 2.1.5?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I am trying to display some data from mysql 8 in Django 2.1. I created a database db1 and inserted some data into it and tested. All works perfectly.

Then I add this piece of code into views.py:

```
@login_required
def population_list(request):
    names = Population.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('images/image/list.html', {'names': names})
```

inside models.py I have:

```
class Population(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    population = models.BigIntegerField()
    year = models.DateField()
```

inside list.html I add this code:

```
<div id="population-list">
<h3>Names here... </h3>

<tbody>
    <tr>
    {% for name in names %}
        <td>{{ name.name }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</tbody>
</div>
```

However I only see: "Names here..." text, nothing else.
What is my mistake? Why I don't see the database content?
How can I debug it?

Comment: How did you insert data into the database?

Comment: CREATE TABLE test( id SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, year YEAR(4), population BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (id));

Comment: INSERT INTO test ( id, name, year, population ) VALUES ( null, 'Asia', 2000, 4433475358);

Comment: Er. Why did you do that? Why did you create a separate table? How is Django supposed to know to use that table for the Population model? You should allow Django to manage the tables itself via migrations.

Comment: I do not select that "test" table. What is the table name in this case?

Comment: It will be `<app_name>_population`; but, just don't do this. You are using Django, so use Django. Open a Django console, not a MySQL console, and insert the data using the model as described in the tutorial. Or use the admin.

Comment: thanks Daniel for help.

Comment: so, I inserted into <app_name>_population some data, however this still does not display anything.

Comment: ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add a path into urls.py file:
    path('users/', views.population_list, name='population_list')